# Pygame : Controlling two sprites

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

```
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
surf = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
black = (0, 0, 0)
surf.fill(black)
fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.flip()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, name, xx, yy):
        self.name = name
        self.image = pygame.Surface((22, 22))
        self.image.fill((130, 100, 200))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x = xx, y = yy)
        self.x_vel = 0
        self.y_vel = 0
    def speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed
    def update(self, keys):
            if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.y_vel = 3
            elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.y_vel = -3
            else:
                self.y_vel = 0   
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.x_vel = -3
            elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.x_vel = 3
            else:
                self.x_vel = 0
            self.rect.x += self.x_vel
            self.rect.y += self.y_vel
    def update1(self, keys):
            if keys[pygame.K_s]:
                self.y_vel = 3
            elif keys[pygame.K_w]:
                self.y_vel = -3
            else:
                self.y_vel = 0

            if keys[pygame.K_a]:
                self.x_vel = -3
            elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
                self.x_vel = 3
            else:
                self.x_vel = 0
            self.rect.x += self.x_vel
            self.rect.y += self.y_vel
    def draw(self, surface): 
        surf.fill(black)
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

player = Player('Tank', 100, 300)
player2 = Player('Tank2', 200, 500)

def main():
    while True:    
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        player.draw(surf)
        player2.draw(surf)
        player.update(keys)
        player2.update1(keys)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()

        fps_clock.tick(60)

main()
```

Trying to create 2 sprites, one which can be controlled using the arrow keys, the other using the WASD keyset. It only blits one sprite on the image, which can be controlled using WASD. The other can be controlled by arrow keys if  player2.update1(keys) is commented. Please don't beat down on me that much, still kind of a novice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you fill the whole screen with black before you draw each player. That means that when player two is drawn player one gets drawn over with black. Remove line 52 surf.fill(black) from def draw() and add it to the main game loop so that it is only called once.

```
def main():
    while True:
        surf.fill(black)
```